# How to club span tags from a string and add in to an array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string ,its value is

```
“Your <span>name</span>  <span class=“icon icon>is</span>  <span class=“alt”>Henry</span>.May i help you ”
```

and i need to split these based on starting and closing span tags and need the final output should be

```
var newArray=[<span>name</span>,<span class=“icon icon>is</span>,<span class=“alt”>Henry</span>]
```

That is i need to get the span tags in an array with the content of span tag as well.So my length of array  will be 3

Any help will be highly helpful and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary DOM element and then get all `span` tags, then loop through the collection to get `outerHTML`

```js
   var str = "Your <span>name</span><span class=“icon icon>is</span>  <span class=“alt”>Henry</span>.May i help you";
    var spList = $("<div>").html(str).find("span");
    var array = [];
    for (i = 0; i < spList.length; i++)
    {
        array.push(spList[i].outerHTML);

    }
    console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 var str = 'Your <span>name</span>  <span class="icon icon">is</span>  <span class="alt">Henry</span>.May i help you';
str = '<customtag>' + str + '<\customtag>';

var parser = new DOMParser()
var el = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");

var spans = el.getElementsByTagName('customtag')[0].getElementsByTagName('span');
var spanArString = [];
var spanArDom = [];
console.log(spans)
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spanArString.push(spans[i].outerHTML);
    spanArDom.push(spans[i]);
}
console.log(spanArString);
console.log(spanArDom);
```

use spanArString or spanArDom as of your need.
inform me if it work or not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegExp for this

```
var arr = "Your <span>name</span>  <span class=“icon icon>is</span>  <span class=“alt”>Henry</span>.May i help you"

    var newArray = arr.match(/<span[^>]*>[\s\S]+<\/span>/)[0].split("  ");
```